# Change the default ErrorMessage for Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.3

I would like to change the default ErrorMessage which we get on validation in Entity Framework 4.3. We found LanguagePacks for EF4.1 but aren't there any LanguagePacks for 4.3 available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We solved this issue by manually translating all the validation messages we came across!
We used some regular expressions to extract the message-resource string from the final error message.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _errorTranslation;

    private static string TranslateErrorMessage(string errorMessage)
    {
        if (_errorTranslation == null)
        {
            _errorTranslation = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // MaxLength-Attribute
            _errorTranslation.Add(
                @"^The field (.*) must be a string or array type with a maximum length of (.*)\.$",
                @"Das Feld $1 hat eine maximale Länge von $2.");

            // MinLength-Attribute
            _errorTranslation.Add(
                @"^The field (.*) must be a string or array type with a minimum length of (.*)\.$",
                @"Das Feld $1 hat eine minimale Länge von $2.");

            // StringLength-Attribute
            _errorTranslation.Add(
                @"^The field (.*) must be a string with a maximum length of (.*)\.$",
                @"Das Feld $1 hat eine maximale Länge von $2.");

            // Range-Attribute
            _errorTranslation.Add(
                @"^The field (.*) must be between (.*) and (.*)\.$",
                @"Das Feld $1 muss zwichen $2 und $3 liegen.");

            // Required-Attribute
            _errorTranslation.Add(
                @"^The (.*) field is required\.$",
                @"Das Feld $1 wird zwingend benötigt.");
        }

        foreach (var pattern in _errorTranslation)
            if (Regex.IsMatch(errorMessage, pattern.Key))
                return Regex.Replace(errorMessage, pattern.Key, pattern.Value);

        return errorMessage;
    }
```

**edit**
Since nobody answered since I posted my question 5 month ago we came with this bad solution. Is it a shame to ask, why am I voted down for this?